# Does array_unique() modify its array by reference?

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

After I use `array_unique()` on an array, when I `var_dump()` the array, it still has the same content, with duplicates:

```
array(21) { 
[0]=> string(10) "tricou_CRS" 
[1]=> string(10) "tricou_CRM" 
[2]=> string(11) "tricou_CRXL" 
[3]=> string(10) "tricou_CBM" 
[4]=> string(10) "tricou_CBL" 
[5]=> string(10) "tricou_CWS" 
[6]=> string(11) "tricou_CWXL" 
[7]=> string(10) "tricou_CRS" 
[8]=> string(10) "tricou_CRM" 
[9]=> string(11) "tricou_CRXL" 
[10]=> string(10) "tricou_CBM" 
[11]=> string(10) "tricou_CBL" 
[12]=> string(10) "tricou_CWS" 
[13]=> string(11) "tricou_CWXL" 
[14]=> string(10) "tricou_CRS" 
[15]=> string(10) "tricou_CRM" 
[16]=> string(11) "tricou_CRXL" 
[17]=> string(10) "tricou_CBM" 
[18]=> string(10) "tricou_CBL" 
[19]=> string(10) "tricou_CWS" 
[20]=> string(11) "tricou_CWXL" }
```

Which obviously has some duplicates. Now, there's not much code that could help, really, because it's just

```
array_unique($myarr);
var_dump($myarr);
```

So, what am I missing there? Shouldn't `array_unique()` remove the duplicates? Both the type and the content is the same in many of the array's positions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$uniquearr = array_unique($myarr);
var_dump($uniquearr);
```

Always read docs first

- http://www.php.net/array_unique

> ### array_unique
>
> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the filtered array.